# Visual Studio 2010 Patches [Fix]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path

Someone could tell me where I can find the list (or all) patch already available for Visual Studio 2010.I am finding a lot of problems, and his navigation is very slow. Especially with ASP.NET MVC.

If no such list ready, we can use this post to enumerate the problems and their fixes.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page should have all the hot fixes
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

and check out the http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/
its no "fix" but for example, there are replacements for the "add reference" dialog, that are muuuuch faster....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a patch that correct a lot of problems that I've been finding in IntelliSense... It works perfectly for me:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/15/patch-for-vs-2010-rc-intellisense-crash-issue-now-available.aspx

Regards!

Comment: That's for the RC; it's fixed in the shipped version.